# Connect grid with dataset to change grid background

Tags: dataset, grid-layouts

```
data = Dataset[{<|"userId" -> 5346, "A3Grades" -> 56.25`, 
 "ColorCode" -> "Red", "totalpointsA3" -> 36, 
 "Passingpoints" -> 38.4`, "AveragePoints" -> 47.285714285714285`,
  "Pointsreqdforpassing" -> 2.3999999999999986`, 
 "pointsforabvavg" -> 0.`|>, <|"userId" -> 5347, 
 "A3Grades" -> 78.125`, "ColorCode" -> "Green", 
 "totalpointsA3" -> 50, "Passingpoints" -> 38.4`, 
 "AveragePoints" -> 47.285714285714285`, 
 "Pointsreqdforpassing" -> 0.`, 
 "pointsforabvavg" -> 0.`|>, <|"userId" -> 5349, 
 "A3Grades" -> 73.4375`, "ColorCode" -> "Yellow", 
 "totalpointsA3" -> 47, "Passingpoints" -> 38.4`, 
 "AveragePoints" -> 47.285714285714285`, 
 "Pointsreqdforpassing" -> 0.`, 
 "pointsforabvavg" -> 0.2857142857142847`|>}];
```

I want to create a grid, such that the color of the grid background changes according to the ColorCode column of data. I tried the following and few other workarounds, but couldn't figure out how to make the exact association:

`Grid[{{"Color", SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft}, {"Code", SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft}}, Frame -> All, Background -> {{}, data[If[#ColorCode == "Red", Red, LightGray] &]}]`

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

If we define a couple of helper functions...

```
color[row_] := If[row["ColorCode"] === "Red", Red, LightGray]

grid[rows_] :=
  Grid[
    Prepend[Values @ rows, Keys @ First @ rows]
  , Frame -> All
  , Background -> {None, {None, color /@ rows}}
  ]
```

... then we can write:

```
data[grid]
```

[image: data grid with a red and grey colour scheme]

We can easily experiment with the colour function:

```
color[row_] := Symbol @ row["ColorCode"]

data[grid]
```

[image: data grid with a multiple colour scheme]

If so inclined, we could also bundle all this up into a single dataset query operator:

```
data[
   {Values, Keys @* First, Map[Symbol @ #["ColorCode"] &]}
/* Apply[Grid[Prepend[#1, #2], Frame -> All, Background -> {None, {None, #3}}]&]
]
```

[image: data grid with a multiple colour scheme]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I was trying to achieve something like this: `Manipulate[
 Grid[{{performance, SpanFromLeft, 
    SpanFromLeft}, {Switch[Ceiling[performance, 25], 25, 
     StringTemplate["``%"][performance], 50, 
     StringTemplate["``%"][performance], 75, 
     StringTemplate["``%"][performance], 100, 
     StringTemplate["``%"][performance]], SpanFromLeft}}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Roboto"}, 
  Background -> {{}, {Switch[Ceiling[performance, 25], 25, Red, 50, 
      Orange, 75, Yellow, 100, Green], LightGray}}], {{performance, 
   1}, 1, 100}]`

Comment: I want to connect the manipulate to this dataset, such that the color changes according to the color code and A3Grades as I slide performance

Comment: Are you imagining that moving the slider will alter the dataset or that it will only alter the visualization?  If the former, change `data` from a variable to a function takes `performance` as an argument.  If the latter, change `color` to accept `performance` as an argument.  The latter is probably easier, something like `color[performance_][row_] := ...` and `Manipulate[
 data[{..., Map[color[performance]]} /* ...], {{performance, 1}, 1, 
  100}]`.